# Filtering an array of Coredata type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a string in my tableview cell. Now I want to check if that string is in a specific array. And if that array has the string, I want to delete the string from that array. This is what I have tried for that...

Also below, favMessages is an array of coredata object called `FavoritedMessages`

```
var textInCell = cell.historyTextLabel.text

for k in favMessages {
    if let thefavData = k.value(forKey: "favData") as? String {                  
        if sdf == thefavData {
             favMessages = favMessages.filter{$0 != textInCell} // HERE ERROR IS THROWN 'Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'FavoritedMessages' and 'String?''
        }
    }
}
```

How I can resolve it that I'm not able to figure out...

Comment: Write your attribute name instead of StringValue in following code.
favMessages = favMessages.filter{$0.StringValue != textInCell}

Comment: What objects stored in favMessages array?

Comment: What do you mean  `a specific array`?

Comment: @Jacky your suggestion worked. Can you put it up as an answer so I can accept it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your attribute name instead of StringValue in following code.

```
favMessages = favMessages.filter{$0.StringValue != textInCell}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array with strings:

```
var strings = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Elements for removing:

```
var firstElement = "a"
var secondElement = "e"

print("Before removing: ", strings)
//Before removing:  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

[firstElement, secondElement].forEach {
    if let index = strings.index(of: $0) {
        strings.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
print("After removing: ", strings)
After removing:  ["b", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
favMessages = favMessages.filter({$0["Your key name of database"] as! String != "string to be compared"})
```

In your case,

```
favMessages = favMessages.filter({$0["favData"] as! String != textInCell})
```

Hope this helps